# Can't use "conda install pyqt" with proxy internet

Tags: anaconda

How can I install pyqt for my Anaconda setup? 
The installer can't work with the internet proxy settings. Is there an offline installer?
I have tested

```
conda install pyqt
```

Comment: @JustinJDavies `Code ticks` are NOT to be used to highlight text.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the proxy settings in your ~/.condarc file, like

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

If you omit the username and password, conda will prompt you for them. See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html for more information.

Comment: and there is a little problem that is rarely mentioned on the web: where is the `.condarc` file located?

Comment: It's in your home directory. I'll edit the question.